# Constructing a partition and sigma algebras

Tags: calculus, analysis, measure-theory, vector-analysis

> Let $Ω$ be a set and let $E$ $=$ {$A$, $B$} where $A$, $B$ ∈ $Ω$ and none of $A$, $B$, $A$ $∩$ $B$, $A$ \ $B$ are empty. By constructing a partition of $Ω$ based on ${A, B}$ prove that $σ(E)$has 16 members.

Not really sure how to approach this. I've attempted constructing a partition but I'm having trouble tying this to the requirement for the sigma algebra of of $E$ having 16 members. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: what is $\sigma(E)$?

Comment: @gt6989b The sigma-algebra generated by $E$.

Comment: @gt6989b I believe it means the sigma algebra on E.

Comment: What is meant by "let $E = A,B$"?

Comment: @AhmedHussein Fixed to include brackets, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @sinbadh The original notation was the correct one.

Comment: If the original notation is correct, then the statement hasn't sense: For example $\Omega=\{1,2,3,...\}$. Then, $A=1$ and $B=2$ satisfied $A,B\in\Omega$, but wht is $A\cap B$? What is the interesection of two numbers? What means that the number $A=1$ is non-empty or empty?

Comment: @sinbadh http://i.imgur.com/CRUPeBb.png I appreciate that, but that's simply the question as it was given.

Comment: Then, is sure that it is a typo error. The correct is $A,B\subseteq\Omega$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P=\{A\cap B,A^c\cap B,A\cap B^c,A^c\cap B^c \}$. Clearly, $P$ is a partition of $\Omega$.

1) $\sigma(P)=\sigma(E)$: since every element of $P$ is in $\sigma(E)$, then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $P$ is contained on $\sigma(E)$. That is $\sigma(P)\subseteq\sigma(E)$. On the other hand, note that $A=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c)$. Then $A\in\sigma(P)$. On the same way $B\in\sigma(P)$. Then, since $\sigma(P)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$ and $B$, we have $\sigma(A,B)\subseteq\sigma(P)$. This proves $\sigma(P)=\sigma(E)$.

2) Rewrite $P$ as $P=\{E_i\}_{i=1}^4$. Now, by hypothesis, none element of $P$ is empty, and since $P$ is partition, $\sigma(P)$ can be characterized as $\sigma(P)=\{\cup_{i\in I} E_i|I\subseteq\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ (we convent that $\cup_\emptyset E_i=\emptyset$). Since the number of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is $2^4=16$, then $|\sigma(P)|=16$.

Indeed there is a general result: if $A_1,...,A_n\subseteq\Omega$, then $\sigma(A_1,...,A_n)$ has at most $2^{2^n}$ elements. The proof is basically the same that is above.